# How can I put advertising on my MediaWiki site just like at Wikia.com?

Tags: google-adsense, advertising, mediawiki

I want to put some AdSense blocks on a wiki I'm running. I guess that Wikia has highly A/B tested their ad placements so I'm going to follow them a little bit there. Unfortunately [the list of extensions](http://prepaidwithdata.wikia.com/wiki/Special:Version) at Wikia is enormous and it's not clear which ones are used for ads on the wiki.

Here's some related HTML:

```
<div id="WikiaTopAds" class="WikiaTopAds">
<div class="WikiaTopAdsInner">
<div class=" wikia-ad noprint " id="HOME_TOP_LEADERBOARD">
```

It could also be that all the ads are part of the skin but to avoid problems with upgrading I would like to avoid modifying the default MW skin and stick with using extensions. So if Wikia is indeed doing it through the skin, which extensions should I go with?

There are three versions of MediaWiki AdSense extensions (completely different code bases actually) and then there's the MediaWiki Widgets solution.

The Widgets solution is probably quite clean, but then it's creating widgets that are supposed to be inserted into articles. I want the ads to be generically inserted on all pages of a specific namespace instead of manually adding them. Is there a solution for that?

Answer (score 1):

Choose [a skin optimised for ads](https://www.mediawiki.org/w/index.php?title=Special%3ASearch&profile=advanced&search=ads+&fulltext=Search&ns106=1&profile=advanced).

The first result is [Skin:Refreshed](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Skin:Refreshed).